# The use of colon in the middle of a sentence

Tags: colons

Please let me know whether the below sentence is grammatically correct.

I like 3 subjects: English, Mathematics, and Science, but the first one is always my favorite subject.

The reason for raising the question in this forum is the presence of colon in the middle of the sentence.

Kind regards

Comment: It’s not that it’s in the middle, it’s that the three subjects need to be set off with the same symbol on both sides. Using dashes here would be good.

Comment: The colon in front of *but* doesn't work. Use a period, and start the second sentence with *but*. When you use a colon to introduce a list, the list can only be referred to as a whole in a second sentence. Alternatively put everything after the comma into parentheses, and move that in front of the colon. Or use *Science (always my favourite subject)*.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding to my query.

Comment: If I understood correctly, the following sentence is grammatically acceptable:                
I like 3 subjects: English, Mathematics, and Science. But, the first one is always my favorite subject. OR                                                                                                      I like 3 subjects -- English, Mathematics, and Science -- but the first one is always my favorite subject.